# Pass parameter to view action from extended class

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app, yii2-basic-app

I extended "dektrium/yii2-user" controller's class as below, now I want to have `$authItems` in render view file of parent class, how should I pass this variable?

```
namespace app\controllers;
use app\models\AuthItem;
use dektrium\user\controllers\RegistrationController as BaseRegistrationController;
class RegistrationController extends BaseRegistrationController
{

    public function actionRegister()
    {
        $authItems = AuthItem::find()->all();

        return parent::actionRegister();


    }
}
```

**its is main class method**

```
 public function actionRegister()
    {
        if (!$this->module->enableRegistration) {
            throw new NotFoundHttpException();
        }

        /** @var RegistrationForm $model */
        $model = \Yii::createObject(RegistrationForm::className());
        $event = $this->getFormEvent($model);

        $this->trigger(self::EVENT_BEFORE_REGISTER, $event);

        $this->performAjaxValidation($model);

        if ($model->load(\Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->register()) {
            $this->trigger(self::EVENT_AFTER_REGISTER, $event);

            return $this->render('/message', [
                'title'  => \Yii::t('user', 'Your account has been created'),
                'module' => $this->module,
            ]);
        }

        return $this->render('register', [
            'model'  => $model,
            'module' => $this->module,
        ]);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solution could be 
don't invoke the parent::actionRegister();
and add the code directly in your actionRegister
and last add the autItems to the render function array parameters

```
  class RegistrationController extends BaseRegistrationController
  {
      public function actionRegister()
      {
          $authItems = AuthItem::find()->all();

          // return parent::actionRegister();

          if (!$this->module->enableRegistration) {
                throw new NotFoundHttpException();
            }

            /** @var RegistrationForm $model */
            $model = \Yii::createObject(RegistrationForm::className());
            $event = $this->getFormEvent($model);

            $this->trigger(self::EVENT_BEFORE_REGISTER, $event);

            $this->performAjaxValidation($model);

            if ($model->load(\Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->register()) {
                $this->trigger(self::EVENT_AFTER_REGISTER, $event);

                return $this->render('/message', [
                    'title'  => \Yii::t('user', 'Your account has been created'),
                    'module' => $this->module,
                ]);
            }

            return $this->render('register', [
                'model'  => $model,
                'module' => $this->module,
                'authItems' => $authItems;
            ]);
      }
  }
```

Comment: what shoud be view path in render  method ? 
it cant recogonize view i changed to 
`
    return $this->render('user/registration/register', [
            'model'  => $model,
            'module' => $this->module,
            'authItems' => $authItems,
        ]);
`
but not work

Comment: where is your register view ? .. where you have placed your register view? in which directory?

Comment: @scaisEdhe it is in views/user/registration/ directory + view is overrided in web.php config file as 

`
        'view' => [
            'theme' => [
                'pathMap' => [
                    '@dektrium/user/views' => '@app/views/user'
                ],
            ],
        ],`

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this:

**Add a member variable to your extended class, such as:**

```
namespace app\controllers;
use app\models\AuthItem;
use dektrium\user\controllers\RegistrationController as BaseRegistrationController;
class RegistrationController extends BaseRegistrationController
{

    public $authitems;

    public function actionRegister()
    {
        $this->authitems = AuthItem::find()->all();

        return parent::actionRegister();


    }
}
```

**Then in your parent class, do a test to see if that variable is set, such as:**

```
 public function actionRegister()
{

    //.........

    return $this->render('register', [
        'model'  => $model,
        'module' => $this->module,
        'authitems' => (isset($this->authitems)) ? $this->authitems : null;
    ]);
}
```